# Python ValueError when using generators to iterate through a file

Tags: python, file, generator

I want to iterate over the lines of a file, but sometimes there may be a remainder string I need to process before consuming new lines. I also need to pass the iterator to other functions so they can consume lines from the same file. I need to be able to either print the output or store the lines in an array, which is why I need `yield` results instead of directly printing it.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
# "flattens" the iterator and remainder into something I can loop over
def lines(src, rem):
    if rem:
        yield rem
    yield from src

def parse_a(src, rem = None):
    for line in lines(src, rem):
        match line.strip():
            case "{":
                # Process "hello" before consuming new lines
                yield from parse_b(src, "hello")
            case x:
                yield "a: " + x

def parse_b(src, rem = None):
    for line in lines(src, rem):
        match line.strip():
            case "}":
                return
            case x:
                yield "b: " + x

with open("test.txt") as file:
    for line in parse_a(file):
        print(line)
```

test.txt

```
1
2
{
3
4
}
5
6
```

Output:

```
a: 1
a: 2
b: hello
b: 3
b: 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test", line 25, in <module>
    for line in parse_a(file):
  File "test", line 9, in parse_a
    for line in lines(src, rem):
  File "test", line 6, in lines
    yield from src
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

What's going on? If I switch `lines(src, rem)` in the for loops with just `src`, then it processes the lines just fine with no I/O error (of course, then I can't get `parse_b` to process "hello"), but somehow if I `yield from src` from another function it's an error?

Comment: when I run your code, i get: invalid syntax `match line.strip():`

Comment: @perpetualstudent use python 3.10

Comment: @perpetualstudent you might want to check out the new structural matching. https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/